# how to enable innodb in Noinstall Zip Archive MySQL version

Tags: mysql

I want to enable innodb in MySQL. I am using Noinstall Zip Archive with the following command to install it: mysqld-nt --install.

I tried adding the --innodb at the end but seems it doesn't work. I have enabled all commented out partial related to innodb in my.ini file.

please help me with step by step instructions. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the **mysqld-nt** executable use the **mysqld** executable. If I remember correctly mysqld-nt hasn't innodb support compiled in.